# Invalid character ‘u0187′ in ../plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, plugins

**Invalid character ‘u0187′ in ../plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js**

I want to add cordova-plugin-file into my app, but after installing cordova-plugin-file when I start my application I got error message like this

> !JavaScript ERROR: SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u0187' on line 2
>   for
>   http://localhost:62500/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js 
>   !JavaScript ERROR: Error: Module cordova-plugin-file.FileWriter does
>   not exist. on line 1385 for http://localhost:62500/cordova.js

when I open that FileWritter.js with Eclipse, I can’t find that character,Invalid character ‘u0187′ in ../plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue is with cordovasim of red hat Jboss-8.0.1**

After plugin installation, while running the application in cordovasim, file & filetransfer plugin javascript files get appended with some special characters.
Becuase of this, application breaks.

Use command line inteface to install plugin & generate APK
Install APK in mobile. It will work as expected.

*

> Note:Red Hat Jboss-8 version having few issues with Ionic App
>   development(Hybrid App)

*